# Java chat program works on localhost, but not when hosting on Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, serversocket

Long story short, I stole and modified some code from GeeksForGeeks to practice with sockets. Running code modified for localhost works fine on desktop, but when modifying and attempting to host on Heroku, I can't seem get a connection between the server and client. Server appears to launch and run fine on Heroku, and logs connections that I'm not even making (no idea where those are coming from). Client on the other hand seems to connect, but then doesn't do anything when I send a message. Server doesn't even log my attempted connection, so I know it probably isn't even connecting.

Server code: https://github.com/RenegadeB5/socket in /src/main/java/

Client Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client
{

public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
{
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    // establish the connection
    Socket s = new Socket("<my app name>.herokuapp.com", 80);
    
    // obtaining input and out streams
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

    // sendMessage thread
    Thread sendMessage = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {

                // read the message to deliver.
                String msg = scn.nextLine();
                
                try {
                    // write on the output stream
                    dos.writeUTF(msg);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    
    // readMessage thread
    Thread readMessage = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (true) {
                try {
                    // read the message sent to this client
                    String msg = dis.readUTF();
                    System.out.println(msg);
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    sendMessage.start();
    readMessage.start();

}
}
```

I've tried so many different combinations and solutions, and can't find any examples of this being done before. I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong so that I can move on from this headache. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You used `"<my app name>.herokuapp.com"` to connect, are you hiding the name of your app or is this unintentional? It could be the problem.

Comment: I'm hiding the name.

Answer (score 1):

Java Socket and ServerSocket use TPC, which is not supported for free by Heroku. As a result, the server will run fine, but anything being sent via TCP, including connection attempts, will not make it to your server unless they are done via http.